# The type or namespace name 'TaskStackBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Support.V4.App' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, androidx

I updated Xamarin.Forms from 4.8 to 5.0 . Also for Xamarin.Forms 5.0 u need to have min Android 10  Target Framework, so i updated from Android 9.0 to Android 10.0. With this Update i need to change Android.Support to AndroidX. But on this code i get error i don't know how to fix:

```
   var stackBuilder =    Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
                stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

Any suggestion?

error:

```
The type or namespace name 'TaskStackBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Support.V4.App' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type or namespace name 'TaskStackBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Support.V4.App'

This is because the `Android.Support.V4.App` library doesn't work in Android 10. You've set the **TargetFramework** to Android 10 in the project, please use `Android.App.TaskStackBuilder` or `AndroidX.Core.App.TaskStackBuilder` api instead.

```
//var stackBuilder = Android.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);
var stackBuilder = AndroidX.Core.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);

stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

Check the doc: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Comment: Thank you i see now. This fixed my problem. One question. With AndroidX can work on older Android versions?

Comment: Yes, It is compatible with the previous Android version.

Comment: that means i got same functionality but diffrent library?

Comment: The Android.Support api and Android.App api both support the TaskStackBuilder function, the latter has a wider range of applications (e.g supports work on android 10).